# How do you build a secure backend auth in node for social network?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, social-networking

How do you build a secure backend in node for social network. I want to have the minimum features that you would find in say with ASP MVC security model, such as CSRF protection and XSS protection? I am just needing basic auth right now with secure cookies on the client.

I am not needing OAUTH.

Answer (score 0):

For securities such as prevent CSRF or XSS, you may use helmet.

https://github.com/evilpacket/helmet

for more authentication - you should implement -

passport.js

may this help you,

Thanks